# Getting the value of textbox to another html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox in index.html and I want get the value of it and put it to textbox in another html file which is result.html. (they have the same .js file using)

index.html textbox:

```
<input id="txt2" readonly="true" type="number" value="0" name="score" style="border:none;background-color:#f0f2f7">
```

result.html textbox:

```
<input id="txt3" readonly="true" type="number" value="0" name="score" style="border:none;background-color:#f0f2f7"></td>
```

this is the code where it will automatically go to the other page:

```
if((mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) {
    //window.alert("Time is up.Your score is "+score); // change timeout message as required
    document.getElementById('txt2').value = score;
    window.location = "score.html" // redirects to specified page once timer ends and ok button is pressed
} 
else {
    cd = setTimeout("redo()",1000);
}
```

And how will txt3 get the value of txt2 since they are in different html?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have no serverside help with passing this value across you might want to try using cookies to make the data persistent across pages.

Comment: or research on html5 capabilities. I think there was something like local storage. It might be what you are searching for, might be also totally out of line...

Comment: @MAXIMUM Please consider green-checking answer if answer served your purpose.More details here on how to do so  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

Use query string Like this

```
http://mysite.com/index.html?name=john
```

and get this name on different html page by using javascript

```
function loadPageVar (sVar) {  
  return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(sVar).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
}  

// Would alert the value of QueryString-variable called name  
alert(loadPageVar("name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change result page URL as follows;

```
window.location = "result.html?val="+document.getElementById('txt2').value;
```

**result.html**

```
<input id="txt3" readonly="true" type="number" value="0" name="score" style="border:none;background-color:#f0f2f7"></td>  


<script>
document.getElementById('txt3').value=window.location.search.replace("?val=","");
</script>
```